# Node express using Bootstrap unable to fire button click event

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-4

newbie in Node and ExpressJs. I am creating a Nodejs app using ExpressJS and Bootstrap as below: `<br/>`

1. using VSCode. `<br/>`
2. tools: use npm to install express and npm init to create
   project

**problem:**`<br/>`
When click the btnLogin , there is no event being fired or no code being executed. Please help to solve this problem. In VSCode, How to associate the $?

--- Directory setup

```
  TestProj<br/>
   |<br/>
   |- node_modules<br/>
   |- main.js<br/>
   |- index.js<br/>
   |<br/>
   |- views<br/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; |- design_Files<br/>
    &nbsp;&nbsp; |- signup.html<br/>
```

------- index.js  for Node:

```
  const express = require('express');
  const app = express();
  const path = require ('path');
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));

  var router = express.Router();
  app.use('/', router);

  router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'signup.html'));
  });

  app.listen(5000,() => console.log('Server started'));
```

----------------------- Html and main.js

```js
window.$ = window.jQuery

   $("#btn-login").click(function() {
  
      var mailformat = /^w+([.-]?w+)*@w+([.-]?w+)*(.w{2,3})+$/;
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();
  
      if(email != "" && password != "")
      {
  
       if(email.match(mailformat))
       {       
            //var result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
  
             result.catch(function(error)
             {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;
           
                window.alert("Message :" + errorMessage);
   
             });
         } else {
  
             window.alert("Please enter a valid email");  
         }
       
  
       }else {
  
        window.alert("please fill out all required fields");  
       }
  
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Sign up</title>
          
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-3edrmyuQ0w65f8gfBsqowzjJe2iM6n0nKciPUp8y+7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!-- MATERIAL DESIGN ICONIC FONT -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design_files/fonts/material-design-iconic-font/css/material-design-iconic-font.min.css">

      <!-- STYLE CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="design_files/css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="wrapper" style="background-image:url('design_files/images/registerback.jpg')">

     <div class="inner">
           <div class="image-holder">
            <img src="design_files/images/registration-form-1.jpg">
            </div>

            <form action="">
              <h3> Register</h3>
    
              <div class="form-wrapper">
                   <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control">
                     <i class="zmdi zmdi zmdi-email"></i>
              </div>
    
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                  <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi zmdi-lock"></i>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-wrapper">
                  <input id="confirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control">
                   <i class="zmdi zmdi zmdi-lock"></i>
                </div>
    
                <div class="form-group container-login100-form-btn">
                  <button id="btn-signup" type="button">
                    Register
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-arrow-right"></i>
                  </button>   
               </div>
                 
               <div class="w-full text-center" style="margin-top:49%; font-size: 15px;">
    
                 <a href="signin.html" class="text-dark">
                    Already have an account?
                  </a>
                </div>
              
          </form>         
     </div> 
   
  </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<scipt src="main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I read all you code and noticed some points to show.

### - Static Files

Let's start by the most important thing. ExpressJS not serves all your files by default, it means that your main.js is not accessible by the HTML page. If you try to access the file in the url you will get a error.

`http://localhost:5000/main.js` **Cannot GET /main.js**

To serve static files like css, images and javascript, you need to do the same thing you did to `views` folder in your index.js, tell to ExpressJS to serve the static files you need.

Create a `public` folder and move `main.js` inside it.
Now add this line to your index.js.

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`

This way, everything inside public folder, is available to your pages.

### - Typos

You have some typos in your code, the first one I saw in your html page, to import your main.js you wrote **scipt** instead of `script`.

The next mistake was the name of your button and it's click handler.
In your page you created your "Register" button with `id="btn-signup"` but in your javascript `main.js` you are handling the click for `#btn-login`

### Tips

You don't really need to do `window.$ = window.jQuery` to access jQuery.
Once it's loaded before your main.js, you can use it easy with no tricks.

And it's a good thing to run all your code after the document is loaded.
You can do it by

```
$('document').ready(function(){
   // all your code here
   console.log('Ready to go!');

   $("#btn-signup").click(function() {
      // ...
   });

})
```

And to finish, `console.log()` is your best friend, use and abuse from it, to understand  whats happening with your code. Hope you understand the long explanation. Stay safe!

Comment: Thank u so much for the explanation and use of static file. your explanation  is great helper. Just need to clarify.  The bootstrap form or form , I should not put anything for action -attribute and I should not use button of submit Type? What will happen for cases of  have and have not of using form action and Submit button for Jquery in this case for NodeJs. Thanks

Comment: When you use form without action attribute, this will send the form to your current page with the specified method, in case you not pass a method attribute, it will be GET by default. The button of type ```submit```, you only need this type if you're using inside a form, this way you can handle the submit event fired by the form when you click the button.

Comment: your code suggestion is ok. I was confused between using html and Nodejs with firebase.
If this index.js contain all the function in main.js and use it for Nodejs, when user click the btn-sigup, the Jquery code will get called and executed in index.js. so,I should not use form action-attribute if I m not sending it to any page for further processing. I hope you can enlighten me on this. Thanks

Comment: do you think you can help me again? When I use index.js for Nodejs, this will cause problem like $ is not defined. I will post it in another thread. This post is ok using two folders to contain javascript. let me know so I can give you the thread Number. Thanks

Comment: Yup! I hope so, send me the thread number when you have it.

Comment: Thanks. appreciate. here the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62384682/firebase-is-not-defined-when-added-firebase-script-in-index-js-in-nodejs-applica

Answer (score 0):

You have added a click listener to non-existent element. Your signup button's id is different from the listener.

```
   $("#btn-signup").click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

      var mailformat = /^w+([.-]?w+)*@w+([.-]?w+)*(.w{2,3})+$/;
      var email = $("#email").val();
      var password = $("#password").val();

      if(email != "" && password != "")
      {

       if(email.match(mailformat))
       {       
            //var result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)

             result.catch(function(error)
             {
                var errorCode = error.code;
                var errorMessage = error.message;

                window.alert("Message :" + errorMessage);

             });
         } else {

             window.alert("Please enter a valid email");  
         }


       }else {

        window.alert("please fill out all required fields");  
       }

  });
```

Comment: I have another signIn.html, sorry for the mistake. treat it as btn-signup,What need to be done for btn-signUp. how to setup js file and the bootstrap html

Comment: above code should work for btn-signup, have you tried it?